# Manifest File HTTP Call

Tags: android, httprequest, android-manifest

I am performing an OAuth2 request on an API EndPoint. 
My CallBack URI is specified both in the settings page of my application at the EndPoint, and in my Activity. If I understand correctly I still need to set an Intent Filter in my Manifest File.

I will get back a Code from the EndPoint..

The question is: How do I set the Intent Filter in my Manifest File?

Manifest File now..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gebruiker.scribetest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="???"/>
                <data android:mimeType="???"/>
                <category android:name="???"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12674116/3111083.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have added in my Manifest File..   See answer below, still not working..